# Draw a flowchart with LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, flow-charts, smartdiagram

I know it is not good to ask this question.
But I am out of time and idea how should I start?
My supervisor ask me to use `LaTeX` than document for this figure below which I had draw in `.doc` file.

[image]

Comment: I'd use Ti*k*Z for this. It's learning curve is *very* steep, but it gets the job done. Cremer's short [tutorial](https://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf) is a very good place to start, and probably will get you to be able to do most, if not all, of your diagram. If not, here are lots of knowledgeable people.

Comment: Probably you could use the smartdiagram package.

Comment: I would draw the picture outside of latex in a vector format (pdf) and then overlay the text only if I were out of time.

Answer (score 9):

A short code with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[pdf, svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}
\sffamily
\psset{framearc=0.3,framesep=5pt}
\begin{psmatrix}[colsep=-0.75, rowsep=0.25]
\psDefBoxNodes{SA}{\psframebox{\eqparbox{FC}{Sample \\Acquisition}}}\\
   & \psDefBoxNodes{SC}{\psframebox{\eqparbox{FC}{Sample \\Checking}}} \\
    & & \psDefBoxNodes{DSC}{\psframebox{\eqparbox{FC}{Dimensionality\\ Sample Check}}} \\
    & & &\psDefBoxNodes{SST}{\psframebox{ \eqparbox{FC}{Sample Synthesis \\Techniques}}} \\
\end{psmatrix}
\psset{linecolor=Silver, doubleline, doublesep=0.35, doublecolor=Silver, arrows=->, arrowlength=0.8, arrowsize=0.6, arrowinset=0}
\foreach \s/\t in{SA/SC, SC/DSC, DSC/SST}{\ncangle[offsetA =0.8, angleA=-90, angleB=180]{\s:bl}{\t:Cl}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: enter code here]

Comment: thanks. Can i ask if I am able to reduce the font size? This is because when I paste in a conference paper, it appears quite big.

Comment: Just add `\small` or `\footnotesize`  or whatever you want before the `psmatrix` environment

Answer (score 8):

Pure TikZ picture, simplified version of your image:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = -1mm and -1mm,
  start chain = A going below right,
   arr/.style = {-{Triangle[length=4mm,width=6mm]}, 
                 line width=4mm, gray!75},
   box/.style = {draw, rounded corners=3mm, semithick,
                 text width=28mm, minimum height=16mm,
                 inner xsep=3mm,
                 font=\sffamily, align=flush left, on chain=A},
                        ]         

% nodes in chaon
\node[box] {Sample Acquisition}; % A-1
\node[box] {Sample Checking};
\node[box] {Dimensionality Sample Check};
\node[box] {Sample\\ Synthesis\\ Techniques};
%
\draw[arr] (A-1) |- (A-2);
\draw[arr] (A-2) |- (A-3);
\draw[arr] (A-3) |- (A-4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or as little bit more complex picture's code, with out-lined arrows drawn as small pictures `pic`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = -1mm and -1mm,
  start chain = A going below right,
   arr/.style = {-{Triangle[length=4mm,width=6mm]}, 
                 line width=4mm, gray!75},
   box/.style = {draw, rounded corners=3mm, semithick,
                 text width=28mm, minimum height=16mm,
                 inner xsep=3mm,
                 font=\sffamily, align=flush left, on chain=A},
     ARR/.pic = {\draw[semithick, fill=gray!40] 
                 (0,0) |- ++ (1.0, -0.6) -- ++ (0,0.2) -- ++ (0.6,-0.4)
                       -- ++ (-0.6,-0.4) -- ++ (0,0.2) -| ++ (-1.4,1) -- cycle;}    
                        ]         

% nodes in chaon
\node[box] {Sample Acquisition}; % A-1
\node[box] {Sample Checking};
\node[box] {Dimensionality Sample Check};
\node[box] {Sample\\ Synthesis\\ Techniques};
%
\pic at (A-1.south) {ARR};
\pic at (A-2.south) {ARR};
\pic at (A-3.south) {ARR};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There's a very simple reason for the use of Mathcha :o)))))). No MWE created by the user and with my answer I simply informed him that if you need simple images use a simple tool like Mathcha. I have delete my answer :-) Always thanks...a billionssss.

Comment: @sebastiano Thanks for the information regarding the tool Mathcha!

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner :o) welcome always.

Comment: @Zarko,  Thanks. Is there a way to reduce the font size? This is because when I paste in a conference paper, it appears quite big.

Comment: @aan, of course. Instead of `font=\sffamily, ` you an write `font=\small\sffamily`. If I correctly remember, I show you example where this image is in two column document. There I reduce font size.

Comment: @Zarko, thanks. Brillant. You save my life.

Comment: @Zarko, can you help me the last chance? My supervisor asked me change the flow char layout, it killing me. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531388/a-simple-flow-char-in-latex