# How to fit a tikzpicture in a double column spacing in a conference paper?

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts, smartdiagram, single-sided

This is a follow up to [Draw a FlowChart with LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529343/draw-a-flowchart-with-latex?noredirect=1#comment1338828_529343).

How can I fit my tikzpicture in a one-side column?

[image]

in this two column paper

[image]

My MWE used is below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = -1mm and -1mm,
  start chain = A going below right,
   arr/.style = {-{Triangle[length=4mm,width=6mm]}, 
                 line width=4mm, gray!75},
   box/.style = {draw, rounded corners=3mm, semithick,
                 text width=28mm, minimum height=16mm,
                 inner xsep=3mm,
                 font=\sffamily, align=flush left, on chain=A},
                        ]         

% nodes in chaon
\node[box] {Sample Acquisition}; % A-1
\node[box] {Sample Checking};
\node[box] {Dimensionality Sample Check};
\node[box] {Sample\\ Synthesis\\ Techniques};
%
\draw[arr] (A-1) |- (A-2);
\draw[arr] (A-2) |- (A-3);
\draw[arr] (A-3) |- (A-4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just place it inside  `\begin{figure*} ... \end{figure*}`

Comment: @koleygr. Thanks. I just tried. It appears to be a large figure covering 2 columns, instead of only one column.

Comment: You can draw this figure smaller :-), for example narrower nodes' shapes, smaller font, different node placement (horizontally shifted to the left in vertically to down). I will redesign it ASAP.

Comment: @aan Sorry ... I thought you wanted to fit it in two columns ... Didn't read carefully ... You may add a `\def\MyScale{0.5}` before the `tikzpicture` environment and then add the option `scale=\MyScale` as a first option of the tikzpicture like `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\MyScale]` and change all the "red" sizes above to e.g `{-1*\MyScale mm}` instead of `-1mm` ... Then adjust the scale to your desired output ... This will give full flexibility except of the font that you could also change to `\small` or whatever in the options too...

Comment: @koleygr. Thanks for you reply. Thanks a lot. my deadline submitting this is tomorrow!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MWE you use one column document (default option), but show desired result with two columns ... See, if the following work around your image gives what you expected:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 1mm and -5mm, % <---
  start chain = A going below right,
   arr/.style = {-{Triangle[length=4mm,width=6mm]},
                 line width=4mm, gray!75, shorten >=-5mm},  % <---
   box/.style = {draw, rounded corners=2mm, semithick,
                 text width=19mm, minimum height=16mm, % <---
                 inner xsep=2mm, 
                 font=\small\sffamily, align=flush left, on chain=A}, % <---
                        ]
% nodes in chaon
\node[box] {Sample Acquisition}; % A-1
\node[box] {Sample Checking};
\node[box] {Dimensionality Sample Check};
\node[box] {Sample\\ Synthesis\\ Techniques};
%
    \begin{scope}[transform canvas={xshift=-5mm}] % <---
\draw[arr] (A-1) |- (A-2);
\draw[arr] (A-2) |- (A-3);
\draw[arr] (A-3) |- (A-4);
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Flowchart ...}
    \label{fig:flowchart}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2-6]
\end{document}
```

Changes in image code are marked by `% <---`.

[image]

Comment: thanks, It worked, brillant! I having a difficult time figuring this out, even with the part you changed, also I cannot fully understand well. Thanks once again

Comment: @ann, latter I can add some shot description, what some changes influence on image lookout.

Comment: is fine. Not urgent. I run out of time to study the code, really make it headache. But you can write when you free, can also let others people learn. You are brillant!