# A simple flow char in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, flow-charts, smartdiagram

Is it simple to do this flowchart?
I need to change the layout from  [flow chart](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529343/draw-a-flowchart-with-latex) to horizontal flow chart.
But i still cannot figure out.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way. It uses `chains` and perhaps more importantly `eqparbox` to make sure that all nodes are equally wide without putting in the width by hand. One has to compile twice to get the correct size since `eqparbox` records the sizes of the boxes and writes the maximum in the aux file, so that it can be used in the second run. It informs the user that a second run is necessary with the message `LaTeX Warning: Rerun to correct eqparbox widths.` Anyway, here is the code.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newbox\eqnodebox
\tikzset{equal size/.style={execute at begin
    node={\setbox\eqnodebox=\hbox\bgroup},
    execute at end node={\egroup\eqmakebox[#1][c]{\copy\eqnodebox}}},
    equal size/.default=A}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm]
\begin{scope}[start chain=going below,
    nodes={on chain,draw,minimum height=2.5em,inner xsep=1ex,
        equal size,rounded corners,join,font=\sffamily},
    every join/.style={-{Triangle[length=3mm,width=6mm]},line width=3mm,
        gray!50,shorten >=1mm,shorten <=1mm}]
 \node{Sample generation}; 
 \node{Sample sample techniques}; 
 \node{Sample sample techniques (AA and BB)}; 
 \node{Sample sample techniques (AA and BB)}; 
 \node{Sample sample techniques (AA and BB)}; 
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `rounded cornders` ? (in definition of `box`)

Comment: @Zarko This key wasn't used, I removed it, thanks. The whole `box` style was superfluous, I forgot to remove it.

Comment: I notice that you like to use `scope`. Does this has in this simple diagram some benefits? +1 for use of `eqparbox`!

Comment: Sorry for bother you, you should mentioned that your MWE need to be compiled twice.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks a lot. is there a method to make all the box same length? Can you provide a second solution?

Comment: @Zarko Thanks! The purpose of the scope is to avoid confusion. Often the users want to add nodes that are not on the chain, and all they need to do is to add them outside of the scope. This appears simpler to me than adding a key for each node that is to be on the scope. And there is a message that says that one needs to recompile when it is necessary, but I will be happy to add this information later.

Comment: @aan This is automatic. You only need to compile twice. There is a message that instructs the user to recompile when it is necessary, but I plan to add this once I am at a computer (and not just a mobile device).

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat. I could not understand what is the meaning of `compile 2 times". And also the first code is put before preamble right?

Comment: @aan It only means that you need to run `pdflatex` or any of these scripts twice.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, I am using Overleaf. But it seemed not working on preamnble

Comment: @aan This is surprising. Be assured that this code works on any reasonably new TeX installation. If it does not work on overleaf, then there is something really wrong with overleaf. You may want to contact the overleaf support, this will benefit all overleaf users.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [sane_tikz](https://github.com/negrinho/sane_tikz). See below for the code.

[image]

```
import sane_tikz as stz
import formatting as fmt

box_height = 1.0
box_width = 7.0
box_spacing = 1.1
box_roundness = 0.1
shaft_width = 0.5
shaft_height = 0.4
head_width = 0.35
head_height = 0.8

lst = [
    "Sample generation",
    "Sample sample techniques",
    "Sample sample techniques (AA and BB)",
    "Sample sample techniques (AA and BB)",
    "Sample sample techniques (AA and BB)",
]


def box_with_text(s):
    s_fmt = fmt.rounded_corners(box_roundness)
    return [
        stz.rectangle([0, 0], [box_width, -box_height], s_fmt),
        stz.latex([box_width / 2.0, -box_height / 2.0], s)
    ]


def arrow():
    s_fmt = fmt.fill_color_with_no_line("lightgray")
    a = stz.arrow(shaft_width, shaft_height, head_width, head_height, -90.0,
                  s_fmt)
    return a


boxes = [box_with_text(s) for s in lst]
stz.distribute_vertically_with_spacing(boxes[::-1], box_spacing)

arrows = [arrow() for _ in range(len(lst) - 1)]
for i in range(len(boxes) - 1):
    to_cs = stz.center_coords(boxes[i:i + 2])
    from_cs = stz.center_coords(arrows[i])
    stz.translate_to_coords(arrows[i], from_cs, to_cs)

stz.draw_to_tikz_standalone([boxes, arrows], "flowchart.tex")
```

Generated TikZ code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[rounded corners=0.100000cm] (0.000000, 8.400000) -- (7.000000, 8.400000) -- (7.000000, 7.400000) -- (0.000000, 7.400000) -- cycle;
\node[] at (3.500000,7.900000) {Sample generation};
\draw[rounded corners=0.100000cm] (0.000000, 6.300000) -- (7.000000, 6.300000) -- (7.000000, 5.300000) -- (0.000000, 5.300000) -- cycle;
\node[] at (3.500000,5.800000) {Sample sample techniques};
\draw[rounded corners=0.100000cm] (0.000000, 4.200000) -- (7.000000, 4.200000) -- (7.000000, 3.200000) -- (0.000000, 3.200000) -- cycle;
\node[] at (3.500000,3.700000) {Sample sample techniques (AA and BB)};
\draw[rounded corners=0.100000cm] (0.000000, 2.100000) -- (7.000000, 2.100000) -- (7.000000, 1.100000) -- (0.000000, 1.100000) -- cycle;
\node[] at (3.500000,1.600000) {Sample sample techniques (AA and BB)};
\draw[rounded corners=0.100000cm] (0.000000, 0.000000) -- (7.000000, 0.000000) -- (7.000000, -1.000000) -- (0.000000, -1.000000) -- cycle;
\node[] at (3.500000,-0.500000) {Sample sample techniques (AA and BB)};
\draw[fill=lightgray, draw=none] (3.700000, 7.275000) -- (3.700000, 6.775000) -- (3.900000, 6.775000) -- (3.500000, 6.425000) -- (3.100000, 6.775000) -- (3.300000, 6.775000) -- (3.300000, 7.275000) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=lightgray, draw=none] (3.700000, 5.175000) -- (3.700000, 4.675000) -- (3.900000, 4.675000) -- (3.500000, 4.325000) -- (3.100000, 4.675000) -- (3.300000, 4.675000) -- (3.300000, 5.175000) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=lightgray, draw=none] (3.700000, 3.075000) -- (3.700000, 2.575000) -- (3.900000, 2.575000) -- (3.500000, 2.225000) -- (3.100000, 2.575000) -- (3.300000, 2.575000) -- (3.300000, 3.075000) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=lightgray, draw=none] (3.700000, 0.975000) -- (3.700000, 0.475000) -- (3.900000, 0.475000) -- (3.500000, 0.125000) -- (3.100000, 0.475000) -- (3.300000, 0.475000) -- (3.300000, 0.975000) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```